# Access property setting value in .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, settings

I am able to access the value of a property defined in the Settings.settings file in my class file SomeClass.cs as such:

```
TestProject.Properties.Settings property = Properties.Settings.Default;
string myValue = property.someValue;
```

However, I would like to access property values from my Default.aspx page.
I have tried:

```
<% 
    TestProject.Properties.Settings property = Properties.Settings.Default;
%>
```

It gives an error on the right side for Properties saying: "The name properties does not exist in the current context."

Is it possible to access property items from an .aspx file?
The only alternative I can think of is to create a .cs class that just reads property items and provides getters the .aspx file could use.

Comment: you could also get this to work by creating a method and in the .aspx file do something like this <%=getPropInfo()%> and do the code for the property like you did TestProject.Properties.Settings property ... do that code inside the method and if you need to return the value .. assign that value to a Session["property"] = property if you need me to post this as answer that will work for you, then let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because `Settings` class is defined as `internal`.
You can workaround that with something like this on your code-behind:

...

```
public string Test { get; set; }
```

...

```
this.Test = WebApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.Test;
```

...

And back in your aspx:

```
<%= this.Test %>
```

But I suggest you to use `web.config` to store settings stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a class specifically for retrieving those property values:

Example:

```
public class TestProperties
{
    public static string getValue1()
    {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.Value1;
    }

    public static string getValue2()
    {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.Value2;
    }
}
```

Then in the .aspx file I retrieve the values as such:

```
Value1: <%= TestProperties.Value1() %><br>
Value2: <%= TestProperties.Value2() %><br>
```

If anyone knows of an easier way to do this I'd like to get some comments on it.