# Using c# string property inside a javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following JavaScript and i need to set the "file" to some string
from the c# code.

how can i do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "rtmp://localhost/someFolder/ + VideoFile/,
        height: 240,
        image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
        rtmp: {
            bufferlength: 0.1
        },
        width: 280
    });

</script>
```

c#

```
String VideoFile = "Some video file link"; // example Video01.flv
```

So, the result will be:

file: "rtmp://localhost/someFolder/Video01.flv/,

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Try using `@Json.Encode(VideoFile)` (if you're using Razor)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access property setting value in .aspx file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890136/access-property-setting-value-in-aspx-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create property and set the value at the page load time and access the same in aspx file

**Code behind**

```
public string VideoFile { get; set; }

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoFile = "Video01.flv";
}
```

**Aspx**

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "rtmp://localhost/someFolder/<%= VideoFile %>",
    height: 240,
    image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
    rtmp: {
        bufferlength: 0.1
    },
    width: 280
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value in the code behind and use it in the markup like this:

```
<%= MyUrlVariable %>
```

Comment: Why the extra `%` sign?

Answer (score 1):

Create a public property on your code behind. Notice it has to be public in order to be seen by the markup page. Let's initialize it in page load.

**Code Behind**

```
public string VideoFile {get; set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoFile="myfile.mp4";
}
```

Then change your script so that you embed the property inline.

**Markup**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                        file: "rtmp://localhost/someFolder/<%= VideoFile %>",
                        height: 240,
                        image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
                        rtmp: {
                            bufferlength: 0.1
                        },
                        width: 280
                    });
                </script>
```

For more info about inline server tags, see [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .NET `string` property's value in the markup as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "rtmp://localhost/someFolder/<%= this.VideoFile %>",
        height: 240,
        image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
        rtmp: {
            bufferlength: 0.1
        },
        width: 280
    });

</script>
```

A [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11890136/1810429) speaks to using .NET class properties in markup more generally.