# Access ApplicationSettings values in aspx file

Tags: asp.net

I have properties in Settings file in my asp project. How do we access those values in aspx pages directly??

I have tried creating a class file and accessed. But it gives the following error

Cannot create an object of type `System.Boolean` from its string representation `<%= MyProperties.EnableValue1() %>` for the `Visible` property.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx ?

Comment: No. That is a legacy method. I'm looking for reading values from Properties file which is advanced to <appSettings>

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890136/access-property-setting-value-in-aspx-file

Comment: Yes. Similar to that, that does not work for me. i have even posted the query there. I'm getting the same error when i tried from above link.

Comment: I finally got the solution, we need to use # symbol in place of = in <%= MyProperties.EnableValue1() %>

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution, we need to use # symbol in place of = in <%= MyProperties.EnableValue1() %>

And use DataBind() load all controls.